# PHP and Json insert attribute inside nil attribute

Tags: php, json

i have a script which insert attributes into a JSON file, to do that i use :

```
$jsonContent = json_decode($content,true); 

$dicCurrentContent = $jsonContent[$dicRef];

$jsonContent[$dicRef][] = $currentDic;
```

No problem, i can manage to add new attributes inside attributes, my problem is when the attributes is nil, like that :

```
{"dicHistoriqueCours":[],"dicHistoriqueDevoir":[],"dicHistoriqueInterroDone":[],"dicHistoriqueInterroCorrigee":[]}
```

I use this code :

```
$dicCurrentCours = $jsonContent['dicHistoriqueCours']; 

foreach ($dicCours as $valueTemp)
{
  $jsonContent['dicHistoriqueCours'][] = $valueTemp; 
}
```

And this gave me a malformed JSON file because i get an extra ] at the end of my "dicHistoriqueCours" attributes.

i get an Extra []] :

```
{"dicHistoriqueCours":[{"Mati\u00e8re":"Fran\u00e7ais","intTotal":"10","Titre":"Le Pluriel","Type":"cours","Adresse":"lePluriel","Difficult\u00e9":"3","Prix":"free","intPoint":"7"},{"Mati\u00e8re":"Fran\u00e7ais","intTotal":"5","Titre":"Le Pass\u00e9 Compos\u00e9","Type":"cours","Adresse":"lePasseComp","Difficult\u00e9":"2","Prix":"free","intPoint":"2"},[]],"dicHistoriqueDevoir":[],"dicHistoriqueInterroDone":[],"dicHistoriqueInterroCorrigee":[]}
```

What can i do ?

thanks for all !

Comment: `json_encode()` returns a malformed JSON string whenn you add array entries? That sounds impossible to me.

Comment: "Malformed" how exactly? What happens?

Comment: i have edit my question do you see },[]], at the end of dicHistoriqueCours

Comment: What is the value of `$dicRef`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add only non empty arrays:

```
foreach ($dicCours as $valueTemp) {
  if(!is_array($valueTemp) || !empty($valueTemp)) {
    $jsonContent['dicHistoriqueCours'][] = $valueTemp;
  } 
}
```